# 'valid certification path' issue in magnolia module generator

Tags: maven-3, magnolia, maven-archetype

I tried to generate new magnolia module with maven generator archetype

> mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.4:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/

Archetype throws an exception

> [WARNING] Error reading archetype catalog https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public
>   org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security
>   .provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

run maven with -X and -e options gives overwhelming logging which doesn't add clarity

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it locally and it works for me.

However, when I tried it first it failed because It couldn't access to nexus and later it was all good. When this fails can you also check if you have problems reaching nexus?

In addition, Perhaps they are related to maven settings. Please have a look at https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/DEV/Maven+setup

Cheers,

Comment: Hi Ducaz035 I can open "https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/" in browser. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Regarding "maven settings": This is my 2nd module. The first one was created about a month ago I don't recall any problem running this generator archetype.

Comment: yes, does it work? https://nexus.magnolia-cms.com/content/groups/public/